# Node SASS for preact

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, build-tools, preact

I started a project with `preact-cli` with the *default* template. I installed `node-sass` and `sass-loader`. I changed one of the `.css` file to `.scss` then the whle thing breaks and gives this error.

```
✖ ERROR BabelEsmPlugin: ./routes/profile/style.scss (../node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/webpack/proxy-loader.js??ref--6-0!./routes/profile/style.scss)
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/webpack/proxy-loader.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (./routes/profile/index.js
 @ ./routes/profile/index.js
 @ ./components/app.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ../node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/entry.js
 @ multi ../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 ../node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ../node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/entry webpack-dev-server/client webpack/hot/dev-server
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is for the sass-loader version 8
you should use

`yarn add -D sass-loader@7.3.1`

(or with npm)

`npm add --save-dev sass-loader@7.3.1`

source from https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/880

If you use sass loader options maybe this quick fix could help (its waiting the merge) https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/pull/930

Hope this help you.